# QML , How to Access Element from Another qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to ask simple question for quick solution. I have `ListView` and `Button` in **main.qml** and `Component` in **closingtaskdelage.qml**. Here is file **main.qml**:

```
ListView
{
    id: grid

    delegate:mydelegate


    model: mymodel
    spacing: 5
    orientation:ListView.Vertical
    Layout.preferredWidth: width_commmon
    Layout.preferredHeight: height_body
    Layout.maximumHeight: 800
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    // highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false
    focus: true

    ClosingTaskModel
    {
        id:mymodel
    }

    ClosingTaskDelegate
    {
        id:mydelegate
    }


}

Button
{
    id:finishbutton
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    Layout.preferredWidth: width_commmon
    Layout.preferredHeight:height_endbutton
    text: "İş Emrini Tamamla"
    onClicked:
    {
         // console.log((grid.children["border1"]).id);
    }
}
```

and file **ClosingTaskDelegate.qml**:

```
Component
{
    id:component1

    Rectangle
    {
        signal sendMenuValuestoJS
        height: 200
        width: 200

        Text
        {
            id:text1;
            text:header;
            height:parent.height/2
            //    width: parent.width

            anchors.horizontalCenter:parent.horizontalCenter;
            font.pointSize:20;
            color:"red";
            //  height:parent.height/2
            //  width: parent.width
        }
    }
}
```

Don't care about details. My main problem is: When `onClickButton()` in **main.qml** occurs, **signal** `sendMenuValuestoJS()` must be triggered. This signal must send **string** value as parameter (i.e. send **Text**).
I can't access signal from **main.qml**. I have defined **signal** in the `Component`, but I get following runtime QML error:

```
Component objects cannot declare new signals.
```

How do I *connect* **signal** to some **function**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to to use [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html)?

Here is the idea,

```
/* main.qml */
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Click {
        id: click
        targetto: mouse
    }
}

/* Click.qml */
Item {
    property variant targetto
    Connections {
        target: targetto
        onClicked: console.log("CLICKED!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, :) I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html) is example from official Qt webiste in Signal Handler Attributes chapter.